# Creating Objects with name values from Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array such as `var arr = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Pig", "Cow"];` and I would like to be able to loop through the array to create an object from each element.

```
var zoo = {
Dog : {
    color: brown,
    age: 4
},
Cat : {
    color: black,
    age: 12
```

I have found some solutions for defining the other properties with .keys and .values but I am stuck on how to name the object. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where do you get values from? I mean color and age for each key.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you share the rest of the data you want to join with your array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the solution using **`Array.reduce`**.
reduce provides an elegant way to return desired output based on your array.

```js
var arr = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Pig", "Cow"];

var zoo=arr.reduce((zooObj, animal)=>
  {
    zooObj[animal] = {
        color: 'black', //You can add color based on some logic here
        age: 4 //You can add age based on some logic here
    }
    return zooObj
  }, {})

console.log(zoo) //*Output*: { "Dog": { "color": "black", "age": 4 }, "Cat": { "color": "black", "age": 4 }, "Horse": { "color": "black", "age": 4 }, "Pig": { "color": "black", "age": 4 }, "Cow": { "color": "black", "age": 4 } }
```

Comment: This works beautifully thank you! I need to get my head around the syntax, but that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below:

```js
var arr = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Pig", "Cow"];
var colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Dark", "Yellow"];
var zoo={};
var i = 10;
var colorIndex = 0;
arr.forEach(v=>{
 zoo[v]={};
 zoo[v].age=i++;
 zoo[v].color=colors[colorIndex++];
});
console.log(zoo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it in this way :

```
var objArr = {};
arr.forEach((data, index) => { 

objArr[data] = data; //here you can add what ever value you want to add to that key

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Pig", "Cow"];
var zoo = {};
for (var i of arr ){
  zoo[i] = {};
  zoo[i].age = 'age'; //fill the age
  zoo[i].color= 'your favorite color'; //fill with your favorite color
}
console.log(zoo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do-

```js
var animal = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Pig", "Cow"];
var color=["red","green","blue","orange","yellow"];
var age=[2,5,8,6,23];
var obj={};
 
animal.forEach((e)=>{
    obj[e]={};
    obj[e].age=age[animal.indexOf(e)];
    obj[e].color=color[animal.indexOf(e)];
    
    })
    
    console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below logic.
Here define color and age array and inside loop store this dynamically.

```
var arr = ["Dog", "Cat", "Horse", "Pig", "Cow"];
var colors = ["brown","blak","white","red","gray"];
var ages = ["4","12","5","10","15"];
arr2 = {}
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
arr2[arr[i]] = {};
arr2[arr[i]].color = colors[i]; //fill the age
arr2[arr[i]].age= ages[i];
}
console.log(arr2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brahmpragya/w76xjm5y/29/